# Xml deserialization appends to list

Tags: c#, properties, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize some settings from an xml file. The problematic property/underlying field is one called `AlertColors`. I initialize the underlying field to white, yellow, and red to make sure that a new instance of this class has a valid color setting. But when I deserialize, `_colorArgb` ends up with six values, first three are the initialization values and the last three are the ones that are read from the xml file. But the property `AlertColors` do not append to the field, but changes its elements. Why do I end up with a field with six colors?

Here's the code:

```
    private List<int> _colorArgb = new List<int>(new int[] { Color.White.ToArgb(), Color.Yellow.ToArgb(), Color.Red.ToArgb() });   

    public List<int> AlertColors
    {
        get
        {
            return _colorArgb;
        }

        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(_colorArgb.Count, value.Count); i++)
            {
                if (_colorArgb[i] != value[i])
                {
                    HasChanged = true;
                }
            }

            _colorArgb = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Deserialize(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Logger.Log("Error while loading the settings. File does not exist.");

            return false;
        }

        FileStream fileStream = null;

        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerFactory xmlSerializerFactory =
                new XmlSerializerFactory();
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
                xmlSerializerFactory.CreateSerializer(typeof(Settings));

            Settings deserializedSettings = (Settings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

            GetSettings(deserializedSettings);

            Logger.Log("Settings have been loaded successfully from the file " + filePath);
        }
        catch (IOException iOException)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error while loading the settings. " + iOException.Message);

            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException argumentException)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error while loading the settings. " + argumentException.Message);

            return false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOperationException)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error while loading the settings. Settings file is not supported." +
                invalidOperationException.Message);

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
                fileStream.Close();

            FilePath = filePath;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void GetSettings(Settings settings)
    {
        AlertColors = settings.AlertColors;
    }
```

And the relevant part of the xml file that I'm deserializing:

```
  <AlertColors>
    <int>-1</int>
    <int>-15</int>
    <int>-65536</int>
  </AlertColors>
```

Comment: Just as an aside: you do realize that the iteration for change detection misses for instance setting { White, White} when the current value is { White, White, Blue}?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that if there are two values, it is for the first two. User shouldn't be manually changing them anyways.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4217139/161052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, that's just how `XmlSerializer` works. Unless the list is `null`, it never expects to try and set a value. In particular, **most** of the time, sub-item lists **don't have** a setter - they are things like:

```
private readonly List<Child> children = new List<Child>();
public List<Child> Children { get { return children; } }
```

(because most people don't want external callers to **reassign** the list; they just want them to change the contents).

Because of this, `XmlSerializer` operates basically like (over-simplifying):

```
var list = yourObj.SomeList;
foreach({suitable child found in the data})
    list.Add({new item});
```

One fix is to use an array rather than a list; it always expects to assign an array back to the object, so for an array it is implemented more like (over-simplifying):

```
var list = new List<SomeType>();
foreach({suitable child found in the data})
    list.Add({new item});
yourObj.SomeList = list.ToArray();
```

However, for a fixed number of values, a simpler implementation might be just:

```
public Foo Value1 {get;set;}
public Foo Value2 {get;set;}
public Foo Value3 {get;set;}
```

(if you see what I mean)

Comment: But it does not serialize/deserialize the private `_colorArgb` field. How does it assume that I'm using that field for the property `AlertColors` and append to it?

Comment: why not check if there is a setter...

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired result without changing your data types, you could use a DataContractSerializer (using System.Runtime.Serialization;) instead of the normal XmlSerializer. It doesn't call default constructors therefore you will end up with 3 colours instead of 6.

```
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Settings));
var reader = new FileStream(@"c:\SettingsFile.xml", FileMode.Open);
var deserializedSettings = (Settings)ser.ReadObject(reader);
```

Answer (score 2):

Coming a bit late to the party, but I just ran into this problem as well.

The accepted answer mentions that Arrays are assigned to every time a deserialization occurs. This was very helpful. But I needed a solution that didn't require me to change the type of the properties and rewrite a million lines of code. So I came up with this:

Using XML Serializer attributes you can 'redirect' the serializer to an Array that wraps around the original property.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<int> AlertColors { get; set; } = new List<int>() { Color.White.ToArgb(), Color.Yellow.ToArgb(), Color.Red.ToArgb() });

[XmlArray(ElementName = "AlertColors")]
public long[] Dummy
{
      get
      {
          return AlertColors.ToArray();
      }
      set
      {
          if(value != null && value.Length > 0) AlertColors = new List<int>(value);
      }
}
```

The Dummy property has to be public in order for the serializer to access it. For me however this was a small price to pay, leaving the original property unchanged so I didn't have to modify any additional code.